# CTRL + ALT + L doesn't work anymore

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running on Linux Mint and I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock my keyboard. But now since 2 days it stopped working. Nothing happens when I use this key combination.

When I go to:

Menu > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > System > Lock Screen I see the Keyboard binding and it says <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>ALT</kbd> - <kbd>l</kbd>

So this seems to be OK, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you logged in as a guest user?

Comment: No I am logging on with my own user account